# Samba does not work after upgrade

Tags: networking, upgrade, samba, smb

I am migrating a SuSE server to a new virtual environment. This also includes upgrading to a new version of samba. The old version of `smbd` is 2.2.8, the new has 3.6.3. The "new" SuSE is SLES 11.4.

The `smb.conf`, `smbusers` and `smbpasswd` were copied verbatim. The samba service starts normally, for example with `service smb restart`. From a client, I can perform `NET USE * \\new_server\share` which executes normally, assigning a Z: drive which does become visible in Windows Explorer. When I try to access it from the Explorer, or from the command line with DIR Z: , I am rewarded with "An unexpected network error occurred".

Here is the global section of `smb.conf`:

```
[global]
 workgroup = XXXXXX
 security = share
 guest ok = yes
 guest account = xxxx
 os level = 0
 encrypt passwords = yes
 socket options = SO_KEEPALIVE IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY
 wins support = no
 ; plus a few that seem irrelevant, such as code pages
```

And here is a typical share declaration:

```
[PDF]
 path = /home/xxx/PDF
 public = yes
 writable = yes
 printable = no
 create mask = 0765
```

Things already tried, none making any difference:

- forcing SMB2 with min protocol = SMB2 in the global secition
- adding guest ok = yes and browseable = yes to the share declaration